# macOS: Breakpoint when file is deleted

Tags: xcode, debugging, cocoa, nsfilemanager, unlink

In my old macOS app, written in Objective-C, I am debugging a reproducible problem in which a file package is removed too early during a system frameworks call.  To get a clue, I would like to have the debugger break whenever a file is deleted.  To that end, I have set symbolic breakpoints in Xcode at these symbols:

```
unlink
unlinkat
-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]
-[NSFileManager removeItemAtURL:error:]
```

All of these breakpoints resolve as expected to actual breakpoints, and they break as expected when files are deleted as expected.  But during the troublesome too-early file deletion, no break occurs.

Are there any other functions in macOS which can delete files, for which I should add breakpoints?

BACKGROUND INFORMATION:

The problem occurs in my custom NSDocument subclass, when calling `[super saveDocument]` on a newly-duplicated (as in *File > Duplicate*) but never-before saved document package.  Such document packages reside in `~/Library/Autosave Information/`, and when things work properly, remain there until the Save panel appears, and is subsesquently dismissed.  However, in the bug case, the package disappears immediately when the user clicks `File > Save` (or an Auto Save occurs), apparently causing a later error indicating that the deleted package could not be moved to the path returned by the Save Panel.

I also tried changing the POSIX permissions of that package after it appears, and before clicking *File > Save*, to octal 500.  The idea is that it could not be deleted, and I  also turned on all of my exception and error breakpoints, hoping the mystery deleter would squawk to the debugger console.  Result: The package was not deleted, and, as I had hypothesized, the Save operation succeeded.  But nothing squawked.  So this mystery deleter is indeed the problem, but is apparently both stealthy and forgiving :(

UPDATE 2019-JUL-19:

After 5 days of finding other things to do, I decided to bite the bullet and use DTrace as suggested Ken Thomases.  It worked, showing me that all files in the subject file package were deleted by a call to `libsystem_kernel.dylib__unlink`, which was in turn called by `-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]`.

I do not know why my breakpoints on these functions did not break for these calls, except maybe there is a clue at the bottom of the stack trace, mentioning "xpc".  Is it possible that this file deletion is done by an XPC helper process?  Does DTrace also probe helper processes of the process being probed?  That would be pretty amazing.

Here is an abridged DTrace session transcript:

```
Air2 jk$ sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::unlink*:entry,syscall::rmdir:entry,syscall::rename:entry { printf("time=%d  arg=%s\n", timestamp/1000000000, copyinstr(arg0)); ustack(100); }' -p `pgrep MyApp`
Password:
dtrace: description 'syscall::unlink*:entry,syscall::rmdir:entry,syscall::rename:entry ' matched 4 probes
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  1    178                     unlink:entry time=6562  arg=/Users/jk/Library/Autosave Information/Unsaved MyApp Document.bmco

              libsystem_kernel.dylib`__unlink+0xa
              libremovefile.dylib`__removefile_tree_walker+0x147
              libremovefile.dylib`removefile+0x99
              Foundation`-[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main]+0xba
              Foundation`__NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__+0x11
              Foundation`-[NSOperation start]+0x2db
              Foundation`-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]+0x54
              AppKit`__90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_2+0x90
              AppKit`__89-[NSDocumentController reopenDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2+0xa6
              AppKit`___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke+0x19
              CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__+0xc
              CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks+0x17b
              CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun+0xae8
              CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x1f3
              HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode+0x124
              HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon+0x164
              HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter+0x40
              AppKit`_DPSNextEvent+0x3de
              AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0x548
              ViewBridge`-[NSViewServiceApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0x5f
              AppKit`-[NSApplication run]+0x292
              AppKit`NSApplicationMain+0x309
              libxpc.dylib`_xpc_objc_main.cold.3+0x38
              libxpc.dylib`_xpc_objc_main+0x203
              libxpc.dylib`_xpc_copy_xpcservice_dictionary
              ViewBridge`xpc_connection_handler
              ViewBridge`NSViewServiceApplicationMain+0xbff
              com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService`main+0xc0
              libdyld.dylib`start+0x1
              com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService`0x1
```

(The call in that transcript apparently tried to unlink the file package, which I think would have failed since the package was not empty.  It is followed by several similar calls which walk the package tree, deleting each node, and finally a repeat of that call to delete the package, apparently with success.)

UPDATE 2019-AUG-06

Although we now know the low-level cause of the problem, we still don't know the high-level cause.  I have since discovered that the problem (premature deletion of the temporary document file in `~/Library/Autosave Information`) only occurs in macOS 10.15 Beta 4-5 (the current version) and only when the app is built with App Sandbox OFF.  When App Sandbox is on, the relevant `Autosave Information` is in a different location, in the app's container, so this should be a good clue!  The problem is easily reproducible with a small demo app, Core Data, document-based, which I have submitted to Apple along with a short video.  If anyone has a line to Apple, please direct their attention to FB6937676 !

Comment: Another tool you can use is DTrace. It's largely neutered by System Integrity Protection (SIP), but you can reenable it without completely disabling SIP. Then, you can use the `errinfo` or `dtruss` ready-made DTrace-based tools. If those don't give you the exact info you're seeking, you directly use `dtrace` with a one-liner or small script to get more info.

Comment: Thank you. @KenThomases is correct as usual.  DTrace worked, for some reason, where breakpoints failed.  I  have explained this in an edit to my question.

Comment: I'm glad you found the culprit. I did consider the Save panel being run out-of-process, but wouldn't have thought it would delete anything! Are you selecting Replace when it warns you're overwriting an existing document? With respect to it seeing the syscall in the XPC service: it's not following the process, at all. By default, the `syscall` provider observes the whole system, not the specified process. You would have to put a condition like `/pid==$target/` on the probe to focus on the specified process. Good thing you didn't! ;)

Comment: That explains it, Ken … I know just enough about DTrace to be dangerous, although I'm getting more dangerous :)  Adding `execname` to my DTrace printf logs that the process deleting the document package is indeed not my app's but a process named `com.apple.appkit`.

Comment: Regarding the Save panel, @KenThomases, I am not selecting *Replace* because that sheet never shows.  Also, the deletion only occurs after duplicating (Save As), editing and saving the first document since app launch, and only for the first such duplication of that document.  The *Autosaved* new document is deleted when the Save panel sheet appears.  I am using [BSManagedDocument](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/BSManagedDocument/blob/v0.3.x/BSManagedDocument.m), but its demo app (BSTest) does not have this bug.  Were this thing not so weird, it could be the subject of another question :(

Comment: The issue I was trying to debug, the cause of this question, turned out to be a bug in macOS 10.15 Betas.  Upon retesting in macOS 10.15.1 Beta (19B68f), the bug no longer occurs.  A message I got from Apple implied that it was fixed in the 10.15 GM.

Answer (score 1):

A rename operation will make the source path no longer refer to a file (looks like the file at the source path was deleted). It can also unlink/delete a file at the destination path, although it will be replaced with the file at the source path. So, that would be `rename()`, `renameat()`, `renamex_np()`, and `renameatx_np()`.

Of course, `rmdir()` can remove a directory, but only if it's empty.

Apparently, there's a hidden `delete()` system call. It's described as "delet[ing] a name from the filesystem using Carbon semantics". It's possible the frameworks are using that.

Comment: Thank you, Ken.  I added breakpoints for all six functions you mentioned (including`rmdir` because I just remembered that my document is a package).  But still no break.  I found that `delete()` function in Apple's open source XNU kernel.  Indeed it has quite a strange declaration: `int delete(user_addr_t path) NO_SYSCALL_STUB; } { private delete (Carbon semantics)`.  And the Breakpoint Navigator does not resolve symbol `delete` to `delete()`. Quite stealthy.  I will pound on it some more tomorrow.